# Check if values is present in coordinate intervals

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe containing five columns : x boundaries, y boundaries and a float property, let's call it pmin. Something like that:

```
A = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'xmin':[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,2],
        'xmax':[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3],
        'ymin':[0,1,2,3,4,2,3,1,3],
        'ymax':[1,2,3,4,5,3,4,2,4],
        'pmin':[12,23,54,48,31,42,20,13,8]
    }
)
```

A B dataframe (or numpy array) would contains (x, y, p) triplets.
I need to check if these values match the ones in A, first while not caring about pmin, then with a condition on it (p < pmin).
For example : 
(.3, 1.8, 28) should returns True in the first case and False in the second case.
(.3, 1.8, 21) should returns True in both cases.
(1.4, .8, p) should returns False in both cases.

As real A has tens of thousands of rows and B might have hundreds of thousands of rows, iterating through rows is not doable. Plus, A x and y values are not ordered (they are coordinates of a complex line).

Any idea of an efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: Your expected outputi s not clear to me. Would mind posting the resulting 'df'?

Comment: What I expect is a dataframe, or any other data structure, with as many rows as B and two columns with booleans corresponding to the two cases I introduced.

Comment: B = [(.3, 1.8, 28),
(.3, 1.8, 21),
(1.4, .8, p)]  (where p is any positive number)
should return a 3x2 (3 being the dimension of B's 0 axis) data structure :
[[True, False],
[True, True],
[True, True]].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
B = (.3, 1.8, 28)
m = ((A['xmin']<=B[0])&(A['xmax']>=B[0]))&((A['ymin']<=B[1])&(A['ymax']>=B[1]))
np.any(m), B[2]<A[m]['pmin'].iloc[0] if np.any(m) else False
```

Comment: So basically m is a mask of the correct cell, then it perform the check for pmin on the last line

Comment: I don't have the whole data yet but it works great on samples. I didn't know about np.any, handy :) Thank you very much!